# Print all data in File

Tags: python, file

I'm practicing for my upcoming test and I trying to figure out how to print data inside the FILE.

accounts.txt

```
carl,1234,17500.0
test102,12334,8640.0
test103,123435,5000.0
```

where:

'carl' is username
'1234' is password
'17500.0' is the balance of account
I have this code where it only prints all the lines in the FILE

```
f = open("masters.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

but I need the output to be these:

```
Username: carl
Balance: 17500.0

Username: test102
Balance: 8640.0
```

thank you in advance
the problem above will be a part of my existing program. :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: hello @not_speshal i have ATM Program, already complete but that part above is the problem. i can paste my code here if you want

Answer (score 1):

Split each line at the `,` and print the first and last words:

```
f = open("masters.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    words = line.split(",")
    print(f"Username: {words[0]}\nBalance: {words[-1]}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on the lines to go from one long string to a list. The argument passed to `split` is the character used to cut the string into pieces. For example:

```py
line = "abc,123,pizza"
split_up = line.split(',')
print(split_up)
```

This will return: `['abc', '123', 'pizza']`

And then it's just a matter of indexing the list to get what you want.

```py
for line in lines:
      split_line = line.split(',')
      print("Username:", split_line[0])
      print("Balance:", split_line[2], "\n")
```

Comment: so by splitting, indexing will enter. thank you for this sir @Jonathan Schwarts

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution:

```py
with open('masters.txt') as text:
    for line in text.readlines():
        [username, _, balance] = line.split(',')
        print(f"Username: {username}\nBalance: {balance}")
```

P.S. *don't use `open` without `with`. I can see you did not use `f.close()` in the end. With `with`, you don't have to close the file. It does it automatically for you.*

Answer (score 0):

All other answers are perfectly fine. But you could also use pandas as the accounts.txt file looks like it is in .csv format:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('accounts.txt', names=['username', 'password', 'balance'], index_col=None)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
  print(f'Username: {row["username"]}')
  print(f'Balance: {row["balance"]}\n')
```

Comment: do i need to import csv for this? or just the pandas

Comment: sir @leogoettke i'm getting an error in line 6

Comment: @CarlmaloneMabiog Thank you for the hint! Of course I can't use single quotes for the column name inside the square brackets when being inside a single quote format string. Fixed it by using double quotes for the column names.

Comment: @CarlmaloneMabiog You only need pandas. But instead of writing `import pandas as pd` you could also do `from pandas import read_csv` and then do `df = read_csv( ... )` without the pd prefix - as we do not use any other pandas function and hence don't need to import all of them.

Comment: Noted! I will study further the use of pandas. Thank you for the idea @leogoettke

Comment: Btw Sir @leogoettke , I'm getting an error of `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` pointing at the `'`

Comment: @CarlmaloneMabiog Do you still get those errors after swapping the single quotes with double quotes inside the square bracket? Like in the (by the time of my last answer) corrected code? Because `print(f'Username: {row["username"]}')` works fine for me... :thinking:

Comment: I tried to change the quotes but still having an error. I think the compiler has the problem coz I'm using an online compiler

Comment: SIr @leogoettke , the compiler has the problem, not the code, thanks for the hint of using pandas

Answer (score -1):

```
f = open("masters.txt")
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    l_list = line.strip().split(",")
    print(f"""Username: {l_list[0]}
Balance: {l_list[2]}
""")
```